# What should be the label of Add button?

Tags: forms, buttons, edit

I have a modal dialog which is having a form of adding or updating employee.
I want to know, what should be the label of my Button when it is opened for adding an employee and when editing the employee details.

**I want my button label to be as per Google material design guidelines**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to keep the labels of the buttons self explanatory. You can use the buttons as follows:

[image]

Comment: When editing and saving employee details...Why button label should not be "Update"

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik you can use "Update Details" as well. You can also add descriptive label in your dialog header such as "Edit Employee Details"